# Как получить оригинальную ориентацию картинки, доступную по URL?

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, asp.net-core

Задача состоит в том, чтобы правильно отображать картинку (горизонтально или вертикально) в зависимости от ее `EXIF`-данных.

Сейчас сервер возвращает `url` картинки формата `JPEG`, но когда этот `url` используется как `src` картинки (тег `img`), то ориентация у такой картинки на сайте всегда будет горизонтальной, даже если фото было сделано вертикально с телефона. Если же перейти по url картинки, то в браузере она отобразится в правильной ориентации. Подозреваю, что тег `img` не умеет распознавать ориентацию картинки. Есть css-свойство `image-orientation`, но оно поддерживается только `firefox`, а нужна также поддержка `chrome` и `IE`

Планирую на сервере скачивать картинку и доставать оттуда метаданные `EXIF` для определения ориентации. Но это может быть лишней нагрузкой на сервер. Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Как решали проблему? Какие есть идеи?

Было бы замечательно увидеть кусок реализации, если ориентация определялась на стороне сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подозреваю, что тег img не умеет распознавать ориентацию картинки.

Подозреваю, что ТЕГИ в принципе не умеют ничего. Распознает браузер, но делает это в зависимости от вашего контента. При просмотре чисто рисунка - реагирует на ориентацию, а при использовании его как части HTML-страницы - смотрит исключительно на размеры.

Ищите/пишите полифиллы для нужных вам браузеров.

Обычно картинки поворачиваются специальными либами сразу при закачивании на сервер, и уже там хранятся повернутыми. Тогда же генерятся маленькие превьюшки.

Вот решение для дергания ориентации на клиенте: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584794/accessing-jpeg-exif-rotation-data-in-javascript-on-the-client-side

Comment: Дело в том, что картинки сохраняются на google storage на платном аккаунте, а не на сервере, где развернуто приложение. Сервер хранит относительные урлы к картинкам, и выдает клиенту по необходимости. Картинка загружается на Storage через мобильное приложение. Предлагаете поворачивать картинку в мобильном приложении?

Comment: Очень, кстати, здравая идея. В идеале - с отключаемой опцией автоповорота изображений в настройках. Ну а если вам сгодится вычитывание ориентации на клиенте - добавил ссылку на инглиш-СО в ответ.

Comment: Поставил +1. Но пока не аппруваю. Позже сюда отпишу решение, которое в итоге мы будем использовать

Comment: Пока на другом проекте и этот фикс `OnHold`, так что пока не смогу отписать решение